# Preview Chatter File in Visualforce

Tags: chatter, chatter-file

I've found a lot of people talking about this but no real answers.  What I am trying to do is simple just show a little thumbnail preview of a file in a custom component

```
SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :selectedId
```

and then i though i could do something like

```
 <img src="/services/data/v28.0/chatter/files/{!file.ContentDocumentId}/rendition?type=THUMB120BY90" alt="Click to preview" class="contentThumbnail" title="Click to preview" id="ext-gen7"/>
```

but thats not working?

I also tried going from the Feed itself

```
public Resume__Feed getApprovedPost() {
        return [Select Id, Type, Title, Body, ContentData, ContentFileName from Resume__Feed where ParentID = :selectedId and Type = 'ContentPost'  ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC, Id DESC limit 1];
}
```

but wasnt able to get any of that to display?

My ideal is to display using their little flash file previewer but i'd settle for just getting the thumbnail?

any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will work:

```
SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId 
FROM ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE LinkedEntityId = :selectedId
```

then

```
<img src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId={!file.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId}" 
    alt="Click to preview" class="contentThumbnail" 
    title="Click to preview" 
    id="ext-gen7"/>
```

To download the actual content, the URL is

```
/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!file.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId}
```

Comment: Great that works!  is there a similar way to get a download url for the full file?  is there any supported way to do anything like this?

Comment: Edited download URL into my answer. I don't know of a supported mechanism for doing exactly what you're doing, but you may be able to navigate to those same URLs in Chatter - see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/ and search for `renditionUrl`.

Comment: It appears to be now officially documented: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/04/building-content-rich-visualforce-pages-with-salesforce-crm-content.html