# Is there any way to display (.doc, docx, .ppt ) type attachment content on Visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a .doc type  attachment  , Attachment contains some images and text . I want to show all content of this attachment on vf page. 
I am able to show pdf, images type attachment preview on vf page , issue is only with (.doc, docx, .ppt ) file. it downloads the attachment instead of showing in new tab.

If attachment is 'attach' which is document file and it may contain images and text.
If I convert body to string like this  and show string on vf page in outputtext
string attachbody =  attach.body.tostring();
I am getting error not UTF-8 type string,

if I use this code show string on vf page in outputtext
string attachbody =  base64Encode(attach.body);
I am getting exceed 135 kb error

Your help would be appriciated. Please suggest me sample code. 
OR javascript jquery code if required.

Comment: Please provide code that you use to create attachment ?

Comment: Maybe this question can help: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16016/preview-chatter-file-in-visualforce

Answer (score 1):

This is really down to the browser capability rather than Visualforce.  If you use the same syntax for a .doc as you do for a .pdf, the browser will display a preview if there is a plugin that supports the format.  If there is no plugin configured, the browser will simply download the file for you to open with the executable of your choice.